# Let $\{X_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1}$ be a sequence S.T, for some $N \in \mathbb{N}, X_n = \alpha$ for $n ≥ N$. Show $\{X_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not too sure how to approach this problem. Given the things at my disposal I'm not sure what I'd be able to use.

Theorem1: If a sequence $\{A_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1}$  converges, then it has a unique limit.

Theorem2: If the sequence $\{A_n\}^{\infty} _{n=1}$ converges, then the set $\{A_n| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded.

plus the definition of convergence to a limit and its equivalent using neighborhood method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the definition. I will talk about real sequences here such that we can make it more visual (I want the graph to be $2$-dimensional). Recall, that convergence means that the sequence gets arbitrarily close to some real number $a$. This is formalized as follows:

No matter how small the distance $\epsilon > 0$ is, you have to be able to find some point on the $x$-axis (given by some natural number $N$), such that all $x_n$ (which are the function values visually) with $n \geq N$ (i.e. all elements for the sequence starting from that chosen point) lie in $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ (that means the distance between these $x_n$ and the limit $a$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ and is usually written as $\lvert x_n - a \rvert < \epsilon$).

Now let us take a look at your problem:

Take some $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x_n = \alpha$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus we have that the sequence is constant (with value $\alpha$ if we only look at natural numbers $n \geq N$. This means, we expect that it converges towards $\alpha$. Now you only need to write that down formally. As $n \geq N$, we get

$$\lvert x_n - \alpha \rvert = \lvert \alpha - \alpha \rvert = 0 < \epsilon,$$

which means that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges with limit $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: @EverOlivares No problem. Added a bit more to give you more intuition. Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: I do have one more homework problem which I am working on. The problem seems trivial, however it would be great for you to critic my first impression. I'm not sure how to format the proof through a comment however.

Comment: You can still ask another question, but you should mention that it is homework. Then we will rather give hints which is nice for you to work on your own. That way you will learn more.